# Why is my data not being displayed?

Tags: php

I have a page with radio buttons and when submitted it should display go to a quiz_layout.php page. The layout page is should display a quiz only based on the radio button submitted. Can anyone help me? I'm not sure why my data isn't being displayed.

page 1: quiz_main.php

```
//form for selecting quiz
echo "<form action=/xampp/Website_DataBase/Pvamu_website/quiz/index.php method=post>";
$mysql = "SELECT DISTINCT quiz_name FROM $table";
$mydata = mysql_query($mysql,$con);
while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
    $quizname=$records['quiz_name'];

    echo "<input type=radio name=name_quiz value=".$records['quiz_name'].">".$records['quiz_name']."<br>";
}
echo "<input type=submit value=Submit Continue>";
echo "</form>";
```

Once submitted it should display my quiz based on the selected radio button

quiz_layout.php

```
$name = '';
if ( !empty( $_POST['name_quiz'] ) && $_POST['name_quiz'] != '' ) {
    $name = $_POST['name_quiz'];
}

$resource = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $table.quiz_name = '$name'";

$mydata=mysql_query($resource);

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
     ?>
<div id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class='questions'>
<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><?php echo $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'];?></h2>
<div class='align'>
<input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer1'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans2_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer2'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans3_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer3'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer4'];?></label>
<input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id='next<?php echo $result['id'];?>' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/>
</div>
<?php }?>
</form>
```

The quiz_layout.php is setup to display one question at a time but nothing is displaying. Help and thank you

Comment: You need to give further detail about `not displaying anything`. Have you checked error logs? What is the output of `var_dump($_POST);` in `quiz_layout.php`?

Comment: yes, $table = "questions"; The page worked fine when I had the page just display all question in the database. Now when I try to make it only select questions based on "quiz_name" in the database, I get nothing. It just runs the timer on the page that I have.

Comment: When I remove this set of code it displays all questions one by one when I hit my next button. I've used this set of code before on a different website and worked but don't know why it won't work now.

'$name = '';
if ( !empty( $_POST['name_quiz'] ) && $_POST['name_quiz'] != '' ) {
    $name = $_POST['name_quiz'];
}

$resource = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $table.quiz_name = '$name'";'

Comment: echo var($_POST) = array(1) { ["name_quiz"]=> string(4) "What" } Not sure why my whole string "What is Php?" isn't passing through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your query result or where condition in query(WHERE $table.quiz_name = '$name')? 
"$name" is set or not checked it.

Comment: I think I know the problem but I don't know how to fix it. It's probably echo var($_POST) = array(1) { ["name_quiz"]=> string(4) "What" } Not sure why my whole string "What is Php?" isn't displaying. It's probably looking for quiz_name="What" not "What is Php?" Would you know how to fix this part?

Comment: you can use LIKE operator for eg. LIKE %$_POST%  or use trim function. for eg. trim($_POST).

Comment: That would work. What would I if I want to display the whole string "What is Php?" from the database. If I can get that down, I'll probably be able to fix other issues that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, you forgot quotations in attributes value. Replace all your html code as following.

```
echo "<form action=\"/xampp/Website_DataBase/Pvamu_website/quiz/index.php\" method=\"post\">";
```